# como enviar parametros del reporte principal a los subreportes con jasper reports 6?

Tags: jasper-reports, jaspersoft

Estimados una consulta en cuanto a jasper report, tengo que ejecutar varias consultas que son de diferentes tablas y que reciben los mismos parametros, como haria con los parametros, estaba pensando hacer con subreportes, pero mi pregunta es, se puede enviar los parametros del reporte principal a los subreportes? como lo haria, gracias

Comment: se puede, en las propiedades del componente subreport, habrá una opción para editar parámetros, ahí agrega tu parámetro de envió, y para recibir en el siguiente reporte tan solo hay que declararlo con el mismo nombre y tipo

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte, si se pudo hacer, sin embargo como haria para que cada subreporte entre en una hoja, no me deja, se sobrepone, ni cambiando el ancho y alto se deja, gracias, saludos